# Temporarily disable autocorrect (in Lion)

Tags: macos, autocorrect

Occasionally, when chatting, it is fun to deliberately misspell words, dyaknowadImean?

OS X Lion is autocorrecting my misspellings into completely random words! Does anyone know how I can temporarily, (e.g. by holding down a key as i type the deliberately misspelled word?) disable autocorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences`, Keyboard, Shortcuts. Add a shortcut for All Applications. Give it the keystroke you like. The name should be: "Correct Spelling Automatically".

Comment: I like the way you are thinking - I'll try this...

Comment: It wrks!!!! :-)

Comment: PS There is no need to restart - the keyboard shortcut is activated without a restart.

Comment: Nice. For people who prefer the mouse, an AppleScript might work. Just a thought.